# Trying to get GA event tracking to work

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a Href button on a page that sends people to buy on amazon.
I have set up events in GA.
I have tried 2 different syntaxs to get the event to show both neither have worked.

Here is what Im working with:

```
[button href="https://.../" 
  onClick="ga(‘send’, 
          ‘event’, { 
             eventCategory: ‘Amazon Click’, 
             eventAction: ‘Click’,  
             eventLabel:‘Buy On Amazon’
           }); 
  rel="nofollow" class="amazon"]
  Buy on Amazon
[/button]
```

The first attempt used the same line but it didnt include the eventXXX: portions. It was just the actual event names.

Im trying to add this to a wordpress site that someone else made for me. Any help would be great.

Comment: First question, why you are not using a Tag Manager like GTM or Tealium? With `onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', 'value');`. There is a ga plugin in Worpress use that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not a wordpress guru here, but I would double check if you're allowed to use JS handlers within bracketed code. Also I'd suggest using GA event plugins such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-analytics-events/).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing [Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) and [Analytics tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) (or, at least, fieldsObject with pure event tracking.

You can do either of these two:

*All parameters sent as fieldsObject*

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event'
  eventCategory: 'Amazon Click',
  eventAction: 'Click',  
  eventLabel: 'Buy On Amazon'
});
```

*Using track event implementation*

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Amazon Click', 'Click', 'Buy On Amazon');
```